# Query XML data from a table with XML data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as id,createdate, outputxml as columns in which outputxml is an XML Datatype column which has the info as below

```
<storage xmlns="http://google.com " created-on="2012-12-29">
    <country>India</country>
    <state>tn</point>
    <period type="day" from="2012-12-27" to="2012-12-28" />
    <capacity-total mwh="12898463" mcm="1229.02" country-percentage="6.1%" />
    <net mwh="28004.00" mcm="2.66" />
</storage>
```

I need the output as:

> id, createdate, storage, created-on, country state, period type, from, to, capacity-total mwh, capacity-total mwh, country-percentage
>
> 1    20-01-2012    http://google.com    2012-12-29  abc      tn     day          2012-12-27  2012-12-28     12898463            1229.02                 6.1%

I tried using

```
 select X.N.value(N'(storage/@country)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        X.N.value(N'(storage/@sso)[2]', 'nvarchar(max)')
   from icissso..ssodataoutput as T
  cross apply T.outputxml.nodes(N'/storage/xmlns') as X(N)
```

But its not returning any value. So kindly suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your [XML Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177607.aspx) and use that when accessing the values:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (X XML);
INSERT @T VALUES ('<storage xmlns="http://google.com" created-on="2012-12-29">
                    <country>India</country>
                    <state>tn</state>
                    <period type="day" from="2012-12-27" to="2012-12-28" />
                    <capacity-total mwh="12898463" mcm="1229.02" country-percentage="6.1%" />
                    <net mwh="28004.00" mcm="2.66" />
                </storage>');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://google.com' AS x)
SELECT  [CreatedDate] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/@created-on', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        [Country] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/x:country[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        [State] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/x:state[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        [PeriodType] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/x:period[1]/@type', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        [From] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/x:period[1]/@from', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        [To] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/x:period[1]/@to', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        [capacity-total mwh] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/x:capacity-total[1]/@mwh', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        [capacity-total mcm] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/x:capacity-total[1]/@mcm', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        [country-percentage] = X.value('/x:storage[1]/x:capacity-total[1]/@country-percentage', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    @T;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5811/2)**